# trouble installing JRI (R to java)

Tags: java, macos, r, installation, jri

I'm wondering if anyone has experience with my error message or has any advice.

When I run the ./configure file it runs with no error.  When I run the make file I get

```
make -C src JRI.jar
gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -c -o Rengine.o Rengine.c -g -Iinclude -g -O2 -I/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/include/. -fno-common -I/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/include/. -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64
Rengine.c: In function ‘Java_org_rosuda_JRI_Rengine_rniParse’:
Rengine.c:89: error: too few arguments to function ‘R_ParseVector’
Rengine.c: In function ‘Java_org_rosuda_JRI_Rengine_rniRunMainLoop’:
Rengine.c:181: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘run_Rmainloop’
Rengine.c: In function ‘Java_org_rosuda_JRI_Rengine_rniGetList’:
Rengine.c:313: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘jri_error’
Rengine.c: In function ‘Java_org_rosuda_JRI_Rengine_rniStop’:
Rengine.c:377: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getpid’
make[1]: *** [Rengine.o] Error 1
make: *** [src/JRI.jar] Error 2
```

I've seen the same or similar question asked on other forums but it didn't seem that anyone had there question answered.  Wondering if anyone knew what this means on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the rJava distribution instead (JRI is now part of rJava).